# Is there any way to call Custom Post content in a div in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, wordpress-shortcode

I am creating a shortcode of custom post type and it's working fine but I got an issue when I trying to call **custom post** content in a div it shows it outside of the whole shortcode area

**Here is the code of shortcode[image]**

```
add_shortcode('portfolios-list', 'pf_portfolio_list');

function pf_portfolio_list(){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'portfolios',
    );

    $query  = new wp_query($args);

    if($query->have_posts()) :

        $events   .= '<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">';

        while($query->have_posts()) :

            $query->the_post(); 

            $events    .= '<div class="item">
               <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-lg-7 cust-v-align">
                   <div class="media-img"> '.get_the_post_thumbnail($r->ID, array(600,600)).' </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-5 pl-5">
                   <div class="project-info mt-5">'.the_content().'</div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>';

        endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    $events   .= '</div>';

    endif;

    return $events;

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It works fine when I use **get_the_content()** rather than the_content()